# Запятая в обороте "что(,) казалось"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли тут запятая между "что" и "казалось"? Вроде как нужна, но интуиция почему-то говорит, что она не обязательна.

*Хлопок был таким громким, что(,) казалось, не выдержат стёкла.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Хлопок был таким громким, что (мне) (по)казалось, (что) не выдержат стёкла.**

Запятая не нужна. Запятая была бы нужна, если бы **казалось** было вводным словом. Для проверки нужно либо попытаться развернуть сложноподчинённое предложение (см. выше), либо заменить **казалось** на **казалось бы**, которое, очевидно, вводное. Вряд ли Вы хотели сказать: *Хлопок был таким громким, что, казалось бы, не выдержат стёкла.*

Добавлю пару цитат.

> Он ревел так громко, весело и долго, что казалось, у него лопнут легкие. (Дж.Лондон)
>
> Лоб был наморщен так, что казалось, вся его кожа собрана к переносице. (Павел Мейлахс, журнал "Новый мир")
>
> И они на этом снимке так хорошо улыбались и сидели так тесно обнявшись, что казалось, никогда не расстанутся. (Ф.Искандер)

**Дополнение**.
Цитаты из сборников Д.Э.Розенталя.

1. Розенталь, Сборник правил и упражнений, 2017 г.

> Временами порывы ветра били так неистово, что казалось, вот-вот ветер
>   (на) чисто сдует ночь (Пауст.).

2. Розенталь, Сборник упражнений по русскому языку, 1966 г.

> Ее толстые косы были сплетены, увязаны и уложены вокруг головы так
>   туго, что казалось, ей больно (Казак.)

Обе цитаты я сверил по книгам Паустовского и Казакевича — никаких ошибок в своих сборниках Розенталь не допустил.

Comment: А какова грамматика придаточной части? Это одна предикативная основа или две? Почему между ними стоит запятая? В справочниках по пунктуации таких примеров вроде бы нет. Или есть?

Comment: @Jasmin В моём понимании две предикативных основы. См. для примера "Вопрос № 266170" на Грамоте. В нашем случае "казалось" может быть вводным, наверное, хотя мне такой вариант нравится меньше. Пусть автор решает.

Comment: @Jasmin *В справочниках по пунктуации таких примеров вроде бы нет. Или есть?* — вот я нашёл [какой-то справочник](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=jSsqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA331&lpg=PA331&dq=%22%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%22+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=jp8qRnrVCv&sig=1RW1dUg7RmiICtqRHIebeHPP9U8&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMpZPtjtbcAhXkAJoKHeSEBGo4ChDoATACegQIBxAB#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%22%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F&f=false), но я не знаю его автора.

Comment: Отмечу этот ответ принятым, но Джек Лондон в примерах - это как-то странно. Он же не по-русски писал, в конце-концов. И это его предложение гуглится в совершенно разных переводах, в том числе и с запятой перед "казалось".

Comment: Вопрос у Грамоты: "И казалось, головы всех были полны вистом." Это обычное вводное слово в начале предложения (разумеется, с одной запятой). Материала из нормальных справочников  у Вас нет, а упражнения  в Сети - это не тот источник, которому можно доверять. В общем, я считаю принятый вариант упрощенной грамматикой (с пропущенным союзом БУДТО), разрешение на такое оформление вряд ли можно найти.

Comment: Вообще говоря, принятие ответа не говорит однозначно о его правильности, а вот голосование отчасти говорит, и оно для меня было неожиданным. Никому не захотелось  поддержать вариант, который хотя бы по статистике превосходит принятый, ну просто ни одним голосочком. Что мне после этого думать о форуме,  я не знаю. Почему-то хочется вспомнить  латинскую мудрость: "Я предпочитаю заблуждаться с Платоном, чем быть правым с пифагорейцами".

Comment: @Jasmin Я Вас не понимаю. Вы посчитали ошибочным ответ Грамоты, назвали скан-копию страницы из школьного учебника "упражнениями в Сети", считаете ошибочными сотни цитат в гугло-книгах (тоже в скан-копиях изданных книг). Неужели у Вас не закралось ни тени сомнения, что возможны оба варианта?

Comment: Вы просто не хотите меня понимать. Вот, к примеру, Вы дополнили текст разными словами. Они помогают  понять смысл, но меняют форму предложения, это уже ДРУГОЕ предложение со своими правилами. Рассмотрим теперь придаточную часть: ЧТО  КАЗАЛОСЬ, НЕ ВЫДЕРЖАТ СТЁКЛА. После союза ЧТО две предикативные основы, связь бессоюзная, отношения изъяснительные. Но запятая в БСП для выражения изъяснительных отношений не используется (только двоеточие и тире). Запятая здесь ― нарушение правил, а зачем Вам нарушать правила?

Comment: Вводное слово "казалось" вполне пригодно для обозначения ситуации, почему Вы не хотите им воспользоваться, в каком учебнике вы видели объяснение этой конструкции?А Грамота.ру ― оракул ненадежный: они и выражаются туманно, и ссылок никогда не приводят (просто государство в государстве со своими законами). И тексты в Сети, учебники непроверенных авторов тоже не довод, да они все списывают друг у друга.

Comment: И про ИНТУИЦИЮ  могу сказать: вводные слова в сложных конструкциях не выделяются интонационно, нет для этого возможностей,  поэтому интонацией обозначаются отношения   между центральными блоками. И получается: паузы нет, интуиция мне подсказывает, что и запятой нет.
Ну да ладно, наверное, нашей аудитории уже надоела оппозиция. ДРУЖБА И ВЗАИМОПОНИМАНИЕ ― это намного приятнее. А истина? Да бог с ней, это римляне считали, что «истина дороже дружбы».  А вот наш А.С. Пушкин сказал:  «Тьмы низких истин мне дороже Нас возвышающий обман...»

Comment: @Jasmin Но при чём здесь ДРУЖБА И ВЗАИМОПОНИМАНИЕ? Я легко иду на (интеллигентный) конфликт, хоть и не стремлюсь к этому, и тоже хочу разобраться. Да, я не филолог, и мне не хватает профессиональных знаний для аргументированного спора. Но очень редко так бывает, чтобы какая-то широко распространённая ошибка не обсуждалась и не изучалась. А я не могу найти следов этого, хотя потратил много времени. В следующем комментарии ссылка на какой-то сборник трудов, там явно что-то подобное обсуждается. Но где его взять?

Comment: Вот [ссылка](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=hcxJAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%22+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82&dq=%22%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%22+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyu5y7sNbcAhVHxaYKHUZIAAY4WhDoAQhQMAc).

Comment: Мне нужен разбор предложения без запятой в авторитетном учебнике, а статистика, как я полагаю, в пользу обособления вводного слова с двух сторон.  Я считаю. что это интонационное заблуждение: запятая перед "казалось" ставится на основе только грамматического принципа, паузы там нет (как и при обособлении деепричастных оборотов после союза И, там тоже нет паузы, а запятая ставится).  Меня огорчило не то, что автор принял ваш ответ, а то, что мой ответ не получил ни одного голоса  хотя бы на правах варианта.

Comment: Вот пример из Набокова (там стоит запятая, а в диктантах ее нет): "Когда прошло минут пять после звонка, и никто еще не входил, наступило такое предчувствие счастья, что, КАЗАЛОСЬ, сердце не выдержит, если все-таки стеклянная дверь сейчас откроется..." Откорректировали классика.

Answer (score 2):

Проведя анализ разных вариантов с запятой и без запятой, я пришла к таким выводам.

1) **Два варианта возможны,** если придерживаться следующего **правила.**

(1) **Если вводное слово нельзя убрать из предложения,** то всю конструкцию после союза ЧТО надо считать единой ( это не две предикатиые основы, а вводное слово в начале предложения), и **тогда запятая не ставится:**

Проверка: **Хлопок был таким громким, что не выдержат стёкла.** Мы видим несоответствие времен, поэтому убрать вводное слово нельзя, запятую не ставим:  Хлопок был таким громким, что (**казалось, не выдержат стёкла)**.

(2) **Если вводное слово можно убрать из предложения**, то оно **обособляется с двух сторон.**

**Но та жизнь ... ушла так далеко, что  это была не её жизнь.** [Василий Гроссман.  (1960)] Предложение имеет нормальную грамматику, поэтому вводное слово обособляется с двух сторон.

Но та жизнь ... ушла так далеко, что, **казалось,**  это была не её жизнь. [Василий Гроссман.  (1960)]

2) **Подобного правила я не нашла в учебниках,** поэтому формулирую его **по аналогии с похожими вариантами** (для союза А, для стыка двух союзов).

3) Надо сказать, что в  реальных текстах такое правило могло учитываться, в то же время **во многих случаях выбор запятых делался  формально**, без учета сказанного.  Не знаю, может быть, есть какие-то другие правила.

Answer (score 0):

**Хлопок был таким громким, что, казалось, не выдержат стёкла.**

**Вводное слово обособляется**, это именно вводное слово, а не сказуемое.

Примеры: Шумели тополя, но горы были такие ясные и близкие, что, **казалось**, они начинаются прямо за парком. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 1 (1964)]

Но та жизнь, с художественными выставками, театрами, обедами в ресторанах, с поездками на дачу, с симфоническими концертами, ушла так далеко, что, **казалось**, это была не её жизнь. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 3 (1960)]

Сравнить: С каждым днём всё позднее светало, и лес стал таким прозрачным, что **казалось:** обшарь его вдоль и поперёк ― не найдёшь ни одного листика. [Сергей Козлов. Правда, мы будем всегда? (1969-1981)]

Здесь ***казалось*** ― сказуемое.

Comment: По последнему примеру. Можно же переделать так:

*...и лес стал таким прозрачным, что казалось, будто обшарив его вдоль и поперёк, не найдёшь ни одного листика.*

Здесь, получается, запятая будет уже нужна? Мне кажется, можно и так, и так, потому что никто кроме автора не может сказать, является ли "казалось" тут вводным словом.

Comment: Последний пример отличается по форме от исходного только способом избежать повторяющегося союза "что" в структуре с последовательным подчинением (просто опустить союз, заменить его на "будто" или поставить двоеточие для раскрытия предыдущего предаточного). "Казалось" (= возникала иллюзия, будто...) в обоих случаях относится к основному содержанию.

Comment: В этом примере казалось - сказуемое, союз БУДТО относится к следующей части предложения. Казалось, будто - это изъяснительная связь, здесь правильная грамматика. Пример с двоеточием (вместо БУДТО) я привела.

Comment: Я дополнил свой ответ цитатами из Розенталя.